# How can I change a closed-source class to manipulate the methods within

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm using a 3rd party library and have discovered a performance bug in it during profiling. I can easily fix this by decompiling the offending class and changing the 'getFoo(Bar b)' method to use a LoadingCache. I then just put that file in the same package in my own source and it overrides it. However, the rest of the class is fine and I don't want to have to keep it updated with library updates.

(I'm aware that the function I'm manipulating may change in the future, but this is also a thought exercise as much as anything else)

What I'm looking for is a way to do this without decompiling the class, i.e. using AspectJ / Javassist / some other bytecode manipulator

e.g. change this:

```
public class SlowWorker{
    public static Foo getFoo(Bar b){
        //do long running op using b and return a Foo
    }
}
```

to:

```
public class SlowWorker{
    private static LoadingCache<AdviceDocument, Object> fooCache = CacheBuilder
      .newBuilder()
      .maximumSize(10000)
      .weakKeys()
      .build(new CacheLoader<Bar, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object load(Bar b) throws Exception {
                return getUncachedFoo(b);
            }
        });

    public static Foo getFoo(Bar b){
        return fooCache.get(b);
    }

    public static Foo getUncachedFoo(Bar b){
        Foo result = //long running op on b
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of fiddling and researching, I realised that what I was trying to do was Hot-Swap the code.

For the curious:

- http://www.hotswapagent.org/
- http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: if this is the answer you are looking for then you should mark it as the answer!

Comment: Yup, StackExchange told me I had to wait 24 hours before marking it the answer

Answer (score 1):

If it is an open source library, then get the source, make your updates and compile, then submit your change for the community. They will decide whether or not to add it to the source tree for future releases.

If it is closed source, try contacting the vendor, most closed source licenses prohibit de-compilation. Contacting the vendor may get them to update their library for you and help you to develop a contact at the company.

Comment: It's not open source, and a request is in the works with the vendor, but this isn't about the 'correct' way of doing things, more about whether or not it's possible

Comment: There really is no good way to do this without decompiling if that class is used internally to the library.  If it is primarily used in your application code, you could wrap it in a caching proxy that delegates to the SlowWorker.  Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible? yes! I once had to prohibit external connections to a local running server, so I uncompressed the jar found the class, decompiled it, made the change, called javac, then re-jarr-ed the lib. The tool 'jad' is quite helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately it's mostly used internally within the library. I can indeed manipulate the library itself, but hoping for a way to do it at runtime:)

Comment: Thinking about it some more, this is exactly what hot-swapping does in Eclipse/JRebel.